# What privileges are need for a normal Oracle user to access V$ and DBA_ views?

Tags: permissions, data-dictionary, oracle-19c

I'm connecting to Oracle 19c as `HR` user. I want to execute the following SQL and some dba_... views:

```
select s.sid
      ,s.serial#
      ,s.username
      ,s.machine
      ,s.status
      ,s.lockwait
      ,t.used_ublk
      ,t.used_urec
      ,t.start_time
from v$transaction t
inner join v$session s on t.addr = s.taddr;
```

Oracle tells me the objects doesn't exist. It seems like a permission issue. What privileges are needed for me to access dynamic performance views and DBA_... views?

Comment: which version of oracle? I think the answer will depend on that. Also if you are talking an on prem install where you have full control versus a could one where you have limited will impact that.

Comment: I updated and answer. I'm using Oracle 19c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to allow that user to read **all** system views, you can use

```
grant select_catalog_role to the_user;
```

[Predefined Roles in an Oracle Database Installation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/configuring-privilege-and-role-authorization.html#GUID-A5B26A03-32CF-4F5D-A6BE-F2452AD8CB8A)